# C# - Why is MySQL Server slow in my server machine?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, server, client

I developed a POS like application and during testing with 2 PCs I didn't encounter any problems with the speed. It's just a simple LAN cable setup between 2 computers. But when I deployed it in a client, it ran slow.

The client has 1 PC serving as the admin and the main server, and there are 2 more PCs serving as the cashier. All connected in a router. The cashiers are connected to the admin's PC (main server) to retrieve, insert, update and delete data. I just want to ask if there are processes that needs to be done in MySQL or are there anything wrong with my codes when connecting to the database.

Here's my sample code for connecting to the database, I doubt having problems with it as this has been the standard in connecting to a database and adding records. Just in case I might bore you with codes, you can simply jump to the second code I posted, I have a comment there asking if the initialization of my class is correct. Thanks everyone!

```
class DBConnection
{
    private MySqlConnection connection;
    private MySqlCommand cmd;
    private MySqlDataReader dr;
    private DataTable tbl;
    private MySqlDataAdapter da;
    private DataSet ds;
    private string connectionString;
    private string server;
    private string database;
    private string uid;
    private string password;

    private frmNotifOk myNotification;
    public DBConnection()
    {
        Initialize();
    }
    private void Initialize()
    {
        server = "CASHIER";
        database = "sampledb";
        uid = "root";
        password = "samplepassword";
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    private bool OpenConnection()
    {
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        return true;
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        switch (ex.Number)
        {
            case 0:
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server.");
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

private void CloseConnection()
{
    try
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}

public void AddRecord(String DBQuery, bool showNotif)
{
    string query = DBQuery;
    bool notify = showNotif;
    try
    {
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (notify)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Item successfully added.");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        this.CloseConnection();
    }
}
```

And finally, here's how I use the method in a form:

```
public partial class frmNewCashier : Form
{
    private DBConnection dbConnect;
    string sampleDataSource= "SELECT * FROM SampleTable";

    public frmNewCashier()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Is this the correct place of initializing my DBConnection class?
        dbConnect = new DBConnection();
    }

    private void frmCashier_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            dgvSearchItems.DataSource = dbConnect.DatabaseToDatagrid(dgvSearchItemsDataSource);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

}
```

I put the initialization of DBConnection class in `public frmNewCashier()`, is this the correct place or should I put it in Load event or somewhere? I'm thinking if this has bearing to the slowness of database. Aside from this question, do you know anything that I might have missed that causes the slowness?

Answer (score 0):

First, try pinging from client machine to server which has installed SQL server. If it is taking too much time then there's problem with network connection.

If not, put a debug point and try debugging then identify the location that taking too long. Then you will able to get a answer.

Also, do not forget to close each and every db connection after using that.

Comment: I'm always putting the closing of connection in the `finally` of `try catch` so I got no problems with that. Assuming that debug point is same with break point, which is what I'm using, how will I know if it's taking too much time? Is there any function in breakpoint that measures the time? Or should I just manually check it if it's taking up time to execute something?

Comment: did u try pining to server? how long did it took ?

Comment: there is a option ti check executing time for methods in visual studio, what is the version of vs you using?

Comment: Do a Wireshark/tcpdump trace on the connection. You will see from the trace what took the most time: client, server and/or network.

Comment: Hi @Thilanka, first of all thank you for the reply! Same with you @BJovke. Looks like I'm having problems with loading the database in the Form_Load event. Coz I loaded all the `products` table while grouping each by id and getting the sum of its `stocks`. Then subtracting it to the products sold table to get the remaining stocks. All of that, IN A SINGLE QUERY. Anyway, I'll try both of your solutions in my free time, very much appreciated! :)

Comment: ahh, then the problem is in query right, in your above code, you just put  as a normal select query, update it with real query then we can optimize that.

Answer (score 0):

class DBConnect
    {
        public  MySqlConnection connection;
        private string server;
        private string database;
        private string uid;
        private string password;

```
    //Constructor
    public DBConnect()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    //Initialize values
    public void Initialize()
    {
        server = "localhost";
        database = "db_sea_horses";
        uid = "root";
        password = " " ;
        //password = "123";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    }


    //open connection to database
   public  bool OpenConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        { //0: Cannot connect to server.
            //1045: Invalid user name and/or password.
            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case 0:
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");
                    break;

                case 1045:
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Close connection
   public bool CloseConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

}

---

class DBmethods : DBConnect
 {
     DataSet dataset2;

```
 public void input_sql(string query)
 {
     try
     {
       //open connection
         if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
         {
             //create command and assign the query and connection from the constructor
             MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

             //Execute command
             int x = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              //close connection
             this.CloseConnection();

         }

     }

     catch(MySqlException myex) 
     {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
 }

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////
 /////  select 
 /////////////////////////////////////////////

 public DataSet output_sql(string query,String table_name)
 {


         //Open connection
         this.OpenConnection();

         DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

         MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
         adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
         adapter.Fill(dataset, table_name);
        //close Connection
         this.CloseConnection();
         //return list to be displayed
     return dataset;


 }

}
```

}

---

method calling example

1) insert / update / delete statement

DBmethods dbm = new DBmethods();
dbm.input_sql(" you can  excute  insert / update / delete query");

2) select statement

DataSet ds = dbm.output_sql("select * from storage_bunkers where job_id LIKE '%" + itemname.Text + "%' ", "storage_bunkers");
            DataView myView = ((DataTable)ds.Tables["storage_bunkers"]).DefaultView;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = myView;

Comment: DBConnection class in public frmNewCashier(), this is not  a  best practice